# maximum number/size of videos to load via VBA in PowerPoint?

Tags: vba, video, powerpoint

I was wondering, if there is a maximum number of videos in ppt that one can import via "AddMediaObject2" in VBA?
I get a strange error, if I try to import several videos with the following macro (which is a dummy version just to show the problem) :

```
Sub loadVideos()
Const path As String = "D:\video.avi"    
For folder = 1 To 20
    Debug.Print "folder: " & folder
    Dim sld As Slide
    Set sld = ActivePresentation.Slides.Add(ActivePresentation.Slides.count + 1, ppLayoutTitleOnly)
    sld.Select


    For i = 1 To 8
        Dim oShp As Shape
        Set oShp = sld.Shapes.AddMediaObject2(FileName:=(path), _
            LinkToFile:=msoFalse, _
            SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, _
            Left:=0, _
            Top:=0, _
            Width:=-1, _
            Height:=-1)

    Next i
Next folder
```

End Sub

It works as expected with smaller video files (so code should be alright!?) but I get the error

"Runtime error -214....
Shapes.AddMediaObject2 : Invalid request, PowerPoint cannot insert any video from the chosen file. Check whether the necessary codec for this media format is installed and repeat the procedure.
"

if I use it with larger videos or alternatively increase the number of videos on each slide or the number of slides containing videos.
I doubt that it has something to do with video codecs, because inserting the videos manually works fine and also the videos inserted so far (till the error occurs) work fine. I also checked that RAM is not completely filled by all these inserted videos.
So I suppose there may be some internal stack or cache memory problem in ppt. Is there any restriction to the number or size of media files that can be loaded in ppt?

I would be very grateful, if someone could either tell me that it may be some bug in ppt or may point to some sort of remedy. Maybe I can configure ppt to accept more/bigger videos?

Many thanks.

Comment: "+ some complaint about video codecs" ... the actual text would have been helpful, but it seems likely that the codec necessary for playing the video isn't installed.  Have you tried inserting the same videos in the same order manually to see what happens?

Comment: I thought that it may be unlikely that the codec is the reason, as the same single video inserted manually works perfectly (which I didn't say in the text. Sorry!) and also the videos that are already inserted before the error occurs work fine (the script just stops with an error after a certain amount of video material/files inserted). That's the explanation, why I didn't add the complete text of the error. Actually another reason is, that the remaining error message is in german but that's only a minor obstacle of course. I will translate and add it to the text. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

Same story for me i could only add 8 mpg files (regardles of installed codecs).
Solution is to open and close presentation after adding single file (sample code above)

ps After converting mpg to avi method works fine...

```
    For Each myBrand In Brands
    Set ReturnPPPresentation = PptApp.Presentations.Open(tmpPresenationPath, withwindow:=msoFalse)
    Set mySlajd = PPTTemplate.Slides(2).Duplicate
        With mySlajd
        Set shp = .Shapes.AddMediaObject2(myBrand.MultimediaPath, msoFalse, msoTrue, 218, 118.22, 384.71, 211.77)
        Set shp = Nothing
    End With
    ReturnPPPresentation.Save
    ReturnPPPresentation.Close
    Next myBrand
```